# Selecting the sum of multiple rows as a value in larger query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a (working) query that looks a bit like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Convert(Varchar(150),O.PONumber) AS OrderID, 
CONVERT(varchar, O.OrderDateTime, 111) AS OrderDateTime, 
CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(DAY, 14, O.OrderDateTime), 111) AS DateExpire, 
C.ClientID, 
C.ClientName, 
U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName AS Name
...
```

I would like to add something like this to it:

```
(SELECT 
    SUM((
        SELECT 
            OI.UnitPoints
        FROM 
            Orders O INNER JOIN
            [dbo].[OrderItems] AS OI ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
        WHERE 
            O.PONumber = 72084))) AS TotalPoints
```

Tthe values returned by this:

```
SELECT 
    OI.UnitPoints
FROM 
    Orders O INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[OrderItems] AS OI ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
WHERE 
    O.PONumber = 72084
```

Look like this:

```
UnitPoits
---------
1
2
```

So in this particular instance I am looking for the value assigned to TotalPoints to be 3 (1 + 2).

Comment: OK, what is your question or where are you stuck?

Comment: @user2989408 Ah. Sorry. Wasn't clear. I need help building the (SELECT SUM(...)) AS TotalPoints query

Comment: Move the [SUM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) part of your query to inside the `SELECT`, because you need the sum of a column, as suggested by @BogdanSavluk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` statement to achieve this:

```
SELECT 
    O.OrderID,
    SUM(OI.UnitPoints) as TotalPoints
FROM 
    Orders O INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[OrderItems] AS OI ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
WHERE 
    O.PONumber = 72084
GROUP BY O.OrderID
```